# How do you import a numerically encoded column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a dataset which encodes a number of variables numerically, e.g.:

```
SEX
1 - Male
2 - Female
```

My best guess at how to convert these (so they appear in my dataframe as `Male` and `Female` instead of numbers) is to do something like this:

```
df.SEX.replace({1: 'Male', 2: 'Female'}, inplace=True)
```

Is there a better/more standard way to do this (ideally as part of my call to `pd.read_fwf` or as single function for many columns)--it's a fairly large file and I have a lot of columns to re-encode this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`categories`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html) for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex": [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]})
```

Change the dtype:

```
df["Sex"] = df["Sex"].astype("category")
print(df["Sex"])
Out[33]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    2
Name: Sex, dtype: category
Categories (2, int64): [1, 2]
```

Rename categories:

```
df["Sex"] = df["Sex"].cat.rename_categories(["Male", "Female"])
print(df)
Out[36]: 
      Sex
0    Male
1  Female
2    Male
3    Male
4  Female
5    Male
6  Female
```

I tried it on a ~75k dataset (choosing the most reviewed 30 beers from [beer reviews dataset](https://github.com/yhat/yhat-examples/tree/master/beer-recommender/python))

```
rep_dict = dict(zip(df.beer_name.unique(), range(len(df.beer_name.unique())))) #it constructs a dictionary where the beer names are assigned a number from 0 to 29.
```

`replace` is quite slow:

```
%timeit df["beer_name"].replace(rep_dict)
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop
```

`map` is faster as expected (because it looks for the exact matching):

```
%timeit df["beer_name"].map(rep_dict)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
```

Changing the category of a column takes almost as much as `map`:

```
%timeit df["beer_name"].astype("category")
100 loops, best of 3: 2.57 ms per loop
```

However, after changing, category renames are way faster:

```
df["beer_name"] = df["beer_name"].astype("category")
%timeit df["beer_name"].cat.rename_categories(range(30))
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
```

So, a second `map` would take as much time as the first `map` but once you change the category, `rename_categories` will be faster. <s>Unfortunately, `category` dtype cannot be assigned while reading the file. You need to change the types afterwards.</s>

As of version 0.19.0, you can pass `dtype='category'` to read_csv (or specify which columns to be parsed as categories with a dictionary). ([docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#read-csv-supports-parsing-categorical-directly))