# pandas: grouping by key to cluster messy strings

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a table that looks like this:

```
company_id,company_name
1,Amazon
1,Amazon Ltd
2,Google
1,Amazon
2,Gogle
3,Facebook Ltd
3,Facebook LTD
1,AMAZON
1,AMAZON LTD
2,GOOGLE
3,Facebook
3,Face book
```

So I have a unique identifier for each company, but their textual representation differs. What I strive for is to eliminate these inconsistencies and have something along the lines of:

```
company_id,company_name
1,Amazon
1,Amazon
2,Google
1,Amazon
2,Google
3,Facebook
3,Facebook
1,Amazon
1,Amazon
2,Google
3,Facebook
3,Facebook
```

I'm not dead set on the selection criterion - it can be the most common value within said group, it can be a random one. But what I need is something efficient, because my table has grown to contain millions of rows.

My solution was to create a hash map of unique combos of `id -> name` and then replacing based on these. Something along the lines of:

```
dd = df.drop_duplicates().set_index('company_id').to_dict()['company_name']
df.company_name = df.company_id
df.company_name = df.company_name.replace(dd)
```

Which works fine on smaller sets, but it gets fairly slow and memory inefficient due to the large hash map it creates.

I've also tried a `groupby` based on `company_id` and replacing all the `company_name`s within each group by a random value, but I couldn't get to modify the underlying dataframe (without `.loc`ing it, which is doubly inefficient).

One last option that springs to mind is to create a separate frame with unique values (`df.drop_duplicates('company_id')`) and merge this with the original frame based on `company_id`, but it doesn't sound terribly efficient either.

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me. `df.company_name = df.company_name.replace(dd)` here instead of `replace`  if you use `map` it will be a lot faster. However you need those pairs no matter what so I don't know how you would solve the memory problem. Are you sure that's an issue? How many unique identifiers do you have?

Comment: You don't need `.loc` for reassigning them back to the underlying `DF`. `Groupby.transform` will take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your solution on a fairly large DataFrame using `map` and it looks pretty efficient:

```
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'company_id': prng.randint(10**6, size=10**7), 
                   'company_name': prng.rand(10**7).astype('str')})
# It has 10m unique identifiers each having 10 entries on average
# ranges from 1 to 28.

df.head()
   company_id         company_name
0      985772   0.4097176168442743
1      305711    0.506659503051052
2      435829  0.45049621797963846
3      117952  0.21756825314220174
4      963395  0.07977409062048224
```

Now you can create a mapper between the `company_id`  and the first occurrence of the `company_name` for that id:

```
%%timeit
mapper = df.drop_duplicates(subset='company_id').set_index('company_id')['company_name']
df['company_id'].map(mapper)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.86 s per loop
```

As [Nickil Maveli mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778355/pandas-grouping-by-key-to-cluster-messy-strings#comment70748653_41778355), `transform` is also a possibility although the performance for this particular dataset I created is not as good as map:

```
%timeit df.groupby('company_id')['company_name'].transform('first')
1 loop, best of 3: 2.33 s per loop
```

`.loc` looks pretty inefficient:

```
%timeit df.groupby('company_id').first().loc[df.company_id]
1 loop, best of 3: 26.4 s per loop
```

In general, you might be better off using categoricals for this type of data. See another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937086/2285236).

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `company_id` and access the company id:

```
df.groupby('company_id').first().loc[df.company_id]
```

Result:

[image]

If you want the as a column, reset the index:

```
df.groupby('company_id').first().loc[df.company_id].reset_index()
```

Result:

[image]